# How to avoid any exceptions while converting a java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to generate a JSON string from a complex java object (using Jackson API). While parsing a field I see ClassCastException. The Java objects are not owned by my project so cannot change and fix the issue. Is there any easy way to fix this?

Please note, my code deals with any kind of Java object and doesn't this Java object in particular so I'm looking for something generic where if a field is not parsed successful, just ignore and move to the next one.

```
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            CustomModule module = new CustomModule();
            mapper.registerModule(module);

            ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            ow.writeValueAsString(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can globally disable checking for instance :

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

By default Jackson throws an exception, if it encounters a JSON property that it can not bind to object property.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.